# Changed value in inline edit field can not be saved in MFTF test

Tags: magento2, grid, mftf, inline-editor

In a custom admin grid I try to change a value in an inline edit field and save it afterwords using a MFTF test.
I use `AdminCustomerGridInlineEditorSection` as template and select the inline edit field with a similar selector like `customerGenderEditor`, only change the type to `input`.
This works so far, and I can also change the value in the grid.
Strangely I get an error message, that this field would be required and I should fill it, although I can see the new text.
When I then click on `save` the error message disappears, but the value is not saved.
Does anyone have similar issues and an idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for this issue is to press `Enter` before pressing `save`. This way the error message disappears and the value can be saved.